# Fragment to fragment transaction android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a container a.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.tc.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

it is to display the tab content, which is a listview.  The first tab A is b.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


     <ListView
              android:id="@+id/list"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/lightGrey"
              android:layout_weight="0.8"
              android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
              android:dividerHeight="5.0sp"
              android:focusable="false"
              android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
         </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Inside of A, when user click on individual listview item, I want to replace the current listview with another Fragment i.e. ContentFragment.

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
            int position, long id) {
        ContentFragment c= new ContentFragment();
        c.setArguments(args);
        a.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(xxx, c)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
    }
```

For xxx field, I think I should fill in the a.container? But how can I get it? As inside of the tab A, I am inflater.inflate(R.layout.b, container, false);

Comment: get it using `R.id.container` ?

Comment: It's your Activity that should make the change of fragments. In your Fragment you can call the activity with getActivity() and then request to change Fragment

Comment: R.id.container is wrong, as my layout file (b.xml) for tab A does not have id: container, which exists in a,xml . @Arthur_gg,    a.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace is doing the fragment change, where a is the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can replace fragment like this in tabview

```
 public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment,booleanaddToBackStack,ContextmContext) 
 {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (addToBackStack) 
            {
                transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
            }


            transaction.add(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
            ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

 }
```

Comment: Actually I have tried sth similar before and fragment is not replaced.   a.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(c, "commentList")
                // Add this transaction to the back stack
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    a.getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

Comment: you need to put tab content id transaction.add(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);

Comment: in my case, it is R.id.list, which does not work as well

Comment: instead of R.id.list you need to put R.id.container

Comment: Yes, but the problem is , id:container is in a.xml. However, Tab A is inflated from b.xml, how to access the id:container in a.xml from Tab A?

Comment: or I shall define the fragment replacing function in my main activity. So for Tab A, instead of doing the fragment transaction in itself,  it should call the function on main activity?

Comment: you can create static method in main activity replace fragment and replace your fragment inside main activity or you can create instance on main activity and call that replace method

Comment: This works when I am using replace on transaction. The fragment is replaced, however, I want the back navigation. So I try   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(newFragment,fragmentName)
    .addToBackStack(null).commit(); but this does not work, the new fragment is not shown.

Comment: you can use popback for back navigaton